# JSF: Redirect to url as POST not as GET

Tags: jsf, post, redirect, get, request

I have an JSF page that redirects via `context.getExternalContext().redirect(url);` where the url is sth. like *login.jsf?token=foobar*

What I want now is to send the token via POST not via GET request. So that it doesn´t show up in the url, is this possible with JSF?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not possible with HTTP, so also not with JSF. There are however several ways to achieve the requirement.

Put it in the session scope. In the bean behind the redirected page, read and remove it from the session scope. Or when you're using JSF 2.0, use the flash scope.

Forward to a page containing a POST form pointing to the desired URL, having the token as hidden input value and include some JS code which does `form.submit()` on page load.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can do this by redirecting your backing bean to some temporary page which contain all hidden values and use `form.submit();` Example:

Backing Bean:

```
public String submitValue() {
        return "temp";
}
```

temporary.jsf

```
<h:form id="JsfTemp" prependId="false">
  <h:outputText id="welcomeOutput" value="Test Sending form"/>
  <h:inputHidden id="Merchant_Number" value="#{paymentBean.paymentDetails.merchantNumber}" />
</h:form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitPage() {
    document.getElementById("JsfTemp").action="http://localhost:9090/TestClient/HelloWorld";
    document.getElementById("JsfTemp").submit();
  }
  submitPage();
</script>
```

Comment: This is already mentioned in the 3rd paragraph of the first answer.

Comment: Yup BalusC just wanted to explain that stuff.Thanks for posting that it helped me a lot .