# post submit from bean method

Tags: jsf, redirect, post

Currently in a bean of my jsf application, I use a `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect` to redirect to a certain page. I attached query paramters to the url. This results in a GET request and on some server where my application is deployed this does't work because they block the get request because one of my parameters has a single quote in it. 
The message I get is that this could be a possible XXS attack.
Therefore I want to replace my redirect with query paramteres to a POST sumit. How can I do this?

code currently:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(request.getContextPath() + "/prospect/detail.xhtml?baumuster=1&customer=" + customer);
```

and when customer equals "rue d'arme" then I get the problem.

Is it possible to do a post sumbit from inside my bean? And how do I do it?

Or should I use a general sessionscoped bean and store customer inside that bean and then redirect and get the custmer variable from the general bean?

Comment: have you tried to `URLEncoder.encode(customer)`  , also . read : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5406033/617373

Comment: I have the same blocking error from the server. This is a security thing on the server and I cannot not change is (not my server)

Comment: seen your link to other question. thx

Comment: as I can not comment on @Rikesh who thinks the anwser is not good. It is the correct answer. At least it answers my question.

Comment: Don't your customers have an ID? Or is this a general search term?

Comment: No, not an ID. It is a delimited concatenated string (not originating from my application)