# How do I redirect in this scenario?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

This submits data to `author.setFindwithid()`:

```
<h:form>
            <h:outputLabel value="Id of to Be Edited record"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText value="#{author.id}"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{author.setFindwithid()}"/>
        </h:form>
```

Here is definition of `author.setFindwithid()`

```
public String setFindwithid() throws SQLException{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM authors WHERE id=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1, this.getId());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Author tmp = new Author();

            tmp.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            tmp.setName(rs.getString("name123"));
            list.add(tmp);
        }

        return "UpdateAuthor.xhtml";

    }
```

As it can be seen I have a `list` and I am also redirecting to `UpdateAuthor.xhtml`. I want to make this `list` available in the scope of `UpdateAuthor.xhtml` so that values of `list` can been shown in view. How can I do that?

Comment: Problem has been solved by using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5406033/4913383)

Comment: That question deals with a different problem. You can just load the list in bean associated with target page.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the List in the flash scope so that it will be kept alive across redirection:

In your `setFindwithid` method:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("listName", list);
```

then you'll be able to reference it in `UpdateAuthor.xhtml` view:

```
#{flash.listName}
```

or get it programmatically in a bean:

```
List myList = (List) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("listName");
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out by BalusC, you can ensure the `List` will be kept inside the Flash scope even after a page refresh using the following invocation in the target facelet:

```
#{flash.keep.listName}
```

**See also:**

[Understand Flash Scope in JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194112/understand-flash-scope-in-jsf2)

[How to keep JSF flash scope parameters on page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011836/how-to-keep-jsf-flash-scope-parameters-on-page-reload/25057753#25057753)

Comment: Does that still work when you F5 the redirected page?

Comment: @BalusC: good point, I've edited my answer to make it work after F5 the redirected page

Comment: And when you copypaste the browser address bar URL into a new tab/window?

Comment: Well, for users who want to get an answer on how to make the list available in the scope of the redirected page, Flash scope is an option.
For the OP's specific case (and to have the list available when copypasting the URL), he'd better do what you say in your comment: load the list in a bean associated with the target page.