# JSF redirect to external website with POST from bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I would like to redirect user to external payment website from bean, I would like to do a POST so that sensitive information is not displayed in the URL.  So far, I used below code, but it uses GET, thereby revealing all sensitive information in URL and also lets user to change it.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("https://externalpaymentsite.com/processPayment?pymtAmt=10.00&acctId=123&acctPswd=abc");
```

Comment: POST data can also be seen and changed in http request.

Comment: possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6185549/1400672

Comment: As @Geinmachi noted: Security through obscurity IS no security. You'll better explain the actual Problem, so we can provide you an actual solution.

Comment: I want to redirect users to an external payment page, I have to provide payment site credentials so that all payments go to our account.  What are my options?

Comment: I doubt you need to provide any sort of credential to the website you re using and you shouldn't have to anyway.

Comment: When I say credentials, I meant parameters, as in my example, GET parameters are `acctId=123&acctPswd=abc`